# no .xcodeproj file in cordova app folder

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am developing cordova app. I created test app using command line interface (CLI).

App runs after `cordova emulate` command. But in app folder I cant find .xcodeproj file. I want to open the app folder in xcode.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.xcodeproj and .xcworkspace files can be found at path `${PROJECT_NAME}/platforms/ios/`  :)

Comment: Thx that helped me a lot :)